# Where stored references to heap memory for reference types?

Tags: c#, .net, reference-type

Simple code for example:

```
Object test=new Object();
```

I understand that memory for `test` object allocated into heap.

Quote from MSDN:

> Variables of reference types store references to their data (objects)

But I really can't understand where stored this variable values (references to heap data), into stack or into heap or another place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test` variable is stored on stack - it holds address of object on heap. And object instance is stored on heap.

I suggest you to read [.NET Type Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301569.aspx) article by Jeffrey Richter:

> When an object is allocated from the managed heap, the new operator
>   returns the memory address of the object. You usually store this
>   address in a variable. This is called a reference type variable
>   because the variable does not actually contain the object's bits;
>   instead, the variable refers to the object's bits.
>
> In addition to reference types, the virtual object system supports
>   lightweight types called value types. Value type objects cannot be
>   allocated on the garbage-collected heap, and the variable representing
>   the object does not contain a pointer to an object; the variable
>   contains the object itself. Since the variable contains the object, a
>   pointer does not have to be dereferenced in order to manipulate the
>   object. This, of course, improves performance.

Comment: thanks for answer. Can you add proof from msdn or other source?

Comment: @Frank59 It is quite hard to find documentation on this on msdn, but here is a nice article on the subject http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx?ArticleID=9adb0e3c-b3f6-40b5-98b5-413b6d348b91

Comment: @Frank59 [Value and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx) article says that variables are stored on stack. It also says that reference type instances are allocated on heap. I think you should take a look on Jeffrey Richter CLR via C# book, which describes CLR internals very good

Comment: Slight correction.`test` doesn't hold the address of the object on heap. It holds a _reference_ to the actual address on heap. **"References cannot be treated as addresses by the user, and in fact, they do not necessarily contain an address in the implementation."** [References are not addresses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx)